# Magento setTemplate at run time/programatically

Tags: magento

I have static CMS pages on my website e.g. Privay Policy, Mony Back Gurantee etc. I have placed these links in footer of website from where these pages get opened with standard layout including header,footer and side bars..

I want to place these links as icons on my product pages but I do not want open them in new window. I prefer a fancybox/thickbox for this but I only want the page content to be shown and not header,footer, side bars etc to appear. In brief I want to set empty template for these CMS pages from only links which are on product page.

Can anyone let me know please that what is best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'Design' tab on the Edit CMS Page in the backend to 'overwride' a template to be used you can select the 'layout' from the drop down to be applied to only that page. There are two approaches for adding the new layouts, one is to build your own module that defines one something like in the layout xml for your module

```
<new_layout translate="label" module="page">
    <label>My New Layout</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/new-layout.phtml">
</new_layout>
```

the other option is just to add this to the page.xml of in your templates layout file (and then a new-layout.phtml you want to use in templates folder) this might be a overkill for just editing a block from page to page but its the 'simplest' way.

All this code is untested and written from memory, but should be quite close to what you need.

Alan

Comment: Alan, Thank you for the reply although I didn't understand it completely. I think I did not explain it well. Let me clarify it bit more. I have setup the 2 column right layout and it works quite well for regular page views.

I want same page to be opened with empty layout when clicked from a link other than footer. i.e 

In footer it should show regular page which is working fine.
<a href="www.mysite.com/privacy"> 

On other links I want same page to be opened with empty layout. Something like
<a href="www.mysite.com/privacy?emptylayout">

Comment: In your layout PHTML can you not just add a request and not call the childhtml of the parts your don't want to show.

if($this->getRequest('frm') != 'footer'){ $this->getChildHtml('left.pod'); }

Comment: Thanks Alan, I will try this. I tried to vote you up but it says that I need 15 reputation to do this. This is just my second question so it will take some to raise my reputation up.

Answer (score 0):

this is for cms pages only

go to mage/page/helper/layput.php

modify :-

```
public function applyHandle($pageLayout){     

    $pageLayout = $this->_getConfig()->getPageLayout($pageLayout);

    if(isset('emptylayout'))    {   
            $pageLayout->setCode('empty');
            $pageLayout->setTemplate('page/empty.phtml'); // this will work
            $pageLayout->setLayoutHandle('empty');

        }
            .
            .
            .

   }
```

**//jquery code**

```
 jQuery('.f-left li a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();                         

            var url=jQuery(this).attr('href')+'?emptylayout'; 

            var data= '<iframe width="100%" height="550" frameborder="0" src="'+url+'"></iframe>';
            jQuery('#mask').html(data);
            jQuery.fancybox({
                    'href': '#mask',
                    'afterClose': function() {
                                        jQuery('#mask').html('');

                                        },
                  });

 });
```